# row_number() over ( ) yields identical values in Hive 0.13.0-mapr-1504

Tags: hive, row-number

I thought that row_number() should definitely give distinct values when no partition is defined. However, in my case:

```
create table tb2 as select  row_number() over ( ) as row, tb1.* from tb1;
```

The column "row" does have identical values:

```
hive> select max(row), count(row), count(distinct row) from tb2;
_c0     _c1     _c2
54229   54229   39925
Time taken: 15.374 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Shouldn't max(row) = count(row) = count(distinct row)??

Comment: What does `select count(*) from tbl1` return?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 select count(*) from tbl1 also returns 54229 rows.